# Excel 2010 Disable Right Click Menu

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Good afternoon all,

I'm trying to restrict the right click menu from appearing in an excel worksheet. I've attempted to use the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Sorry!  Right click is disabled!"
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Am I missing something that will let this work?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Codes works for me, do you have your macro security set to disable macros?

Comment: My macro security is set to enable all. Do I have it stuck in the wrong place...?  Should/Can I have it located under a specific Sheet# or does this need to be in a Module?

Comment: In needs to go in the ThisWorkbook module

Comment: That's where I have it. I have another macro that stops the ctrl-c/v/x from doing copy, paste and cut, resp. It works fine. I'm not sure why this event is giving me such headaches.

Comment: have you tried to delete it and add it back?

Comment: I did. And I started an entirely new workbook with only that snippet of code in it. No joy.  Not sure what's wrong with it. Maybe I need to spend the weekend re-evaluating how I'm going about this.  All I really need is to restrict the pasting of any data in one sheet of a workbook.

Comment: Adding it to a single worksheet and using the correct Worksheet_ fixed the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code:

```
MsgBox "Sorry!  Right click is disabled!"
Cancel = True
```

But to specify a worksheet you would need to open that worksheet's code module and put it in the Worksheet_BeforeRightClick event block so that the end result looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Sorry!  Right click is disabled!"
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Edit:
Note that the event within a specific worksheet's module is the "Worksheet_BeforeRightClick" event, but the workbook module has "Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick".  If you want it per sheet, you will need to add the worksheet event to each desired sheet.  If you want it for the whole workbook, you will need to put the workbook event in the workbook module.

For the workbook module, it should look like this ("ThisWorkbook" in the "Book1" project is the selected module in the left pane):
[image]

For the worksheet module, it should look like this ("Sheet1 (Sheet1)" in the "Book1" project is the selected module in the left pane);
[image]

The syntax difference is key.

Comment: Isn't that the same code I have above? I still can't seem to get it to do any even prior to a right click no matter where I put it.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you try to use it you: open the code editor (by either selecting the developer tab and clicking "Visual Basic" or by pressing ALT+F11), then you navigate to the workbook that you want in the pane on the left side and double-click on the worksheet you want from the "Microsoft Excel Objects" folder within that workbook, then put this code there?

Comment: Using worksheet and then putting it in a single worksheet works like charm! Thank you!

Comment: No problem- sometimes it's just a little tweaking needed